# bluemix vm openstack using c++ language

Tags: c#, c++, c, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

a Bluemix customer is planing to deploy its C/C++ (and probably C#) application in Bluemix and by using the Bluemix VM OpenStack. 
The issue is that in the list of supported languages you can not find C/C++ as it is indicated in the documentation that: "You can deploy and run applications that are developed in any of the following languages: Liberty for Java™,SDK for node.js, GO, ASP, .NET5, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails and Ruby Sinatra". What solution can Bluemix offer to the C/C++ (and C#) customers?

Comment: That’s something you should ask Bluemix support, I think.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. But there are two different languages C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 11 IBM has added to Bluemix a .Net Buildpack or set of tools, along with the .Net runtime, giving developers C and C# options.
http://www.informationweek.com/software/enterprise-applications/ibm-bluemix-welcomes-microsofts-net/d/d-id/1320357

The ASP.NET runtime is currently offered as an [experimental service.](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/labs/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways you can deploy an application in Bluemix:

1. Cloud Foundry application
2. Containers
3. Virtual Machines

The statement about the supported languages applies to Cloud Foundry applications. In this case a specific buildpack for a language is required to deploy an application.

If you are using Virtual Machines you can deploy and install any application supported by the operation system you choose for the Virtual Machines, including C or C++. You basically need to install the packages required by C or C++ in the Virtual Machine.